# Is the normalizer of a subgroup of a maximal subgroup contained in that maximal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite group, H a maximal proper subgroup of G and K a subgroup of H.  Is the normalizer of K in G, $N_GK$, a subgroup of H.
Now $N_GK$ is certainly contained in some maximal subgroup, maybe more than one, but why is it contained in H.
This should be really elementary.

---

As is pointed out below, there are trivial counterexamples.  K = {e} for example, or  normal in G. So it es elementarily false.  I will mark this answered.

Comment: What if $K$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: The smallest counterexample uses $G$ of order $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with what you write.

First: it is not true that $N_G(K)$ "is certainly contained in a maximal subgroup"; that's only true if $N_G(K)\neq G$, that is, if $K$ is not normal in $G$... a possibility you never excluded.

Second: It is not necessarily contained in $H$. Here is an example: take $G=S_3\times C_3$, let $H=S_3\times\{e\}$, and take $A$ to be a subgroup of $S_3$ of order $2$, and let $K$ be the subgroup given by $A\times\{e\}$. This is contained in $H$; but its normalizer is $A\times C_3$, which is not contained in $H$.

You have absolutely no reason to think that $N_G(K)$ will be contained in $H$ in general. If $K\triangleleft H$, then you know that $H\leq N_G(K)$ and hence that $N_G(K)=H$ or $G$, but I think that's about all you can say in this generality of setting.

Answer (score 1):

There is one particular case where what you want is true and I think it is general enough that it is worth mentioning here. It is Theorem 9.2.13 in Derek Robinson's book "A Course in the Theory of Groups", p. 266.

> Let $M$ be a nonnormal maximal subgroup of the finite soluble group
>   $G$ and let $|G:M|=p^m$.  If $Q$ is a Hall $p'$-subgroup of $M$, then
>   $N_G(Q) \leq M$.

Comment: I would quibble with “only”; it reads as if to say that if at least one of the assumptions is not satisfied, then the normalizer cannot be contained in $M$. But in general, if you have a normal subgroup of $M$ that is not normal in $G$ you would have the conclusion.

Comment: I have edited accordingly.